# On Safari browser, getting an error: "This form is not secure. Are you sure you want to submit it?", even though the page is secured by HTTPS

Tags: ssl, safari

Any ideas why? The form processes fine in all major browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE) but on Safari we are seeing a pop up that says The Form Is Not Secure. The page is definitely https:// and the SSL is setup appropriately when I reviewed it. Could it be another issue?

Comment: I am getting this as well, with both my page being https and the target page (FB SSO) being https.

Answer (score 3):

Change the link to https:// instead of http:// So basically ad an "s" which let's the browser know the link is secure. It doesn't actually secure the page but it stops the error message. The problem happens when you are sending someone from an https page to an http page so it's the transition that triggers the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any chance the form is contained within an IFRAME that, itself, is *not* pointing to an https url?

Answer (score 0):

check your system date or time is accurate, actually this type of problem related to SSL certificate of particular webpage happend to this reason.